# C++ reading from text file, parsing and adding prices

Tags: c++, file, parsing

The goal is to have the program read from the text file, parse it by the # symbol, and print out the item and the price. It is in a loop so it needs to repeat because there is 3 items. It also needs to count the amount of items (based on the lines) and add all the prices together for a total price. The text file it needs to parse looks like this:

```
hammer#9.95
saw#20.15
shovel#35.40
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include <string> 
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
ifstream invoice("invoice2.txt");
string name;
int count = 0;
int totalPrice = 0;
float price = 0.0;
while(invoice.open())
{
    getline(file, line);
    ++count;
    for (string line; getline(file, line); )
    {
        size_t sharp = line.find('#');  
        if (sharp != string::npos)
        {

                string name(line, 0, sharp);
                line.erase(0, sharp+1);
                price = stof(line);
            cout << "*** Invoice ***\n";
            cout << "----------------------------\n";
                cout << name << "               $" << price << "\n\n";
            cout << "----------------------------\n";
            cout << count << " items:             " << totalPrice;
            }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

The loop needs to repeat until the text file is over then it should break and print the totalprice

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

To start with, why the `while` loop? You don't need that.

Secondly, you skip the first line by having the initial `getline` before the inner loop.

Thirdly, you never add anything to `totalPrice`. And you print every time inside the inner loop. Shouldn't it be printed *after* the loop?

So change to something like the following pseudo-code:

```
if (invoice.isopen())
{
    print_header();

    while (getline())
    {
        parse_line();
        print_current_item();
        totalPrice += itemPrice;
    }

    print_footer_with_total(totalPrice);

    invoice.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the delimiter argument of getline?

```
for (string str; getline(file, str, '#'); ) {
  double price;
  file >> price >> ws;
  totalPrice += price;
  // handle input...
}
// print total etc.
```